# How to customize the interface after selecting an item from a drop down list?

Tags: javascript, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vue-component

Hello I am currently working with Vue.js and Typescript. I would like to customize the interface. 
There is a drop down list, after choosing an item, the interface should be adjusted in the context of the item.

```
<b-form-select
              id="input-topic"
              v-model="form.selectedTopic"
              @change="createForm(form.selectedTopic)"
              :options="dropdownTopics"
              required>
</b-form-select>
```

If an item is selected, e.g. purchase order, this section should be imported dynamically.

```
<section>
      <h2>{{this.$t('order')}}</h2>

      <b-form-row>
        <b-col>
          <b-form-group :label="this.$t('orderNumber')"  label-for="input-orderNumber">
            <b-form-input
              id="input-orderNumber"
              v-model="form.orderNumber"
              trim></b-form-input>
          </b-form-group>
        </b-col>
      </b-form-row>
</section>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to resolve this requirement.

The most simple way is using v-if directive

Step 1: Save your selected option in a state (in component data)

```
data(){
  form: {selectedTopic: 'two'}
  options: ['one', 'two', 'three']
}
```

Step 2: add a v-if directive to your section, so that it is only visible if the option chosen is the one indicated

```
<section v-if="optionSelected === 'two' ">
...
</section>
```

Another option may be using v-router and use watch for observe your selectedTopic, so when the selectedTopic change your do a router push to change the route